# Add report URL to each report in Jasper Report Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need that each report shows its own URL printed somewhere in the report. I´m using JasperReports Versión 5.5.0. Is there any variable that holds this value? Thanks.

Comment: What is `its own URL`?

Comment: When you select a report on the server, they have a URL like this one:  
`https://serverhost/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FReports%ADas&reportUnit=%2FReports%RH%2Info%C3%ADsticas%2FOficial%C3%ADas%2FServices`

Each report generate this kind of URL, I need to print that auto-generated URL on each report.

Comment: Pass the report URL in as a (hidden) parameter to the report then use a [hyperlink](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html) element to display it.

Comment: We have a lot of reports and we will create more. We need a simple way to do that, like a report variable or something. :S